# NHibernate ISQLQuery with byte[] parameter throws error

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, arrays, isqlquery

So, I am trying to use nhibernate to call a stored procedure that saves an image.  My problem is that the query fails with this error:

> The length of the byte[] value exceeds the length configured in the mapping/parameter.

Here is where I attach my parameters to the `ISQLQuery`.  Parameters is a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

```
public void Execute()
{

    string sql = BuildSprocDefinition();
    var query = Session.CreateSQLQuery(sql);

    foreach (var parameter in Parameters)
    {
        if (parameter.Value is int)
            query.SetParameter<int>(parameter.Key, (int)parameter.Value);
        else if (parameter.Value is long)
            query.SetParameter<long>(parameter.Key, (long)parameter.Value);
        else if (parameter.Value is bool)
            query.SetParameter<bool>(parameter.Key, (bool)parameter.Value);
        else if (parameter.Value is byte[])
            query.SetBinary(parameter.Key, (byte[])parameter.Value);
        else
            query.SetParameter(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
    }

    using (var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        query.ExecuteUpdate();
        Session.Flush();
        tx.Commit();
    }
}

protected string BuildSprocDefinition()
{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(String.Format("exec {0} ", storedProcName));

    foreach (var parameter in Parameters)
    {
        sql.Append(String.Format(":{0}, ", parameter.Key));
    }

    if (sql.ToString().EndsWith(", "))
    {
        sql = sql.Remove(sql.Length - 2, 2);
    }

    return sql.ToString();
}
```

In the database, my parameter is type `varbinary(max)` and I am trying to send in a 'byte[]' as the data.

I tried using the specific `SetBinary` and yet this fails.  All other datatypes seem to be working.

I have also tried `query.SetParameter<byte[]>(parameter.Key, (byte[])parameter.Value);` with the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is a bit old question, but i put my answer for new searchers.

for byte[] parameters you can specify the length this way

```
query.SetParameter(parameter.Key, parameter.Value, NHibernate.Type.TypeFactory.GetBinaryType(((byte[])parameter.Value).Length));
```

you need to make sure that the procedure parameter has sufficient length

Comment: Thank you very much for this. have been searching for hours, was looking at the mappings, but that doesn't apply with Session.CreateSqlQuery. Instead of getting the length of the byte array, I just used NHibernate.Type.TypeFactory.GetBinaryType(int.MaxValue).

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate doesn't magically know that the datatype in the database is varbinary(max). You need to specify a large enough length in your mappings (I think the default is 8000 bytes).